# Cannot setup email in Botframework portal

Tags: bots, botframework

While registering Email channel for Microsoft Bot with office 365 id, it shows "Unable To Save" error but somehow again shows Email channel running.
On receiving a new email in Inbox, Email channel gives error as There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Internal Server Error".

Comment: can you please share your code so we can better assist you

Comment: Yes please share more information as Jason requested

Answer (score 0):

> it shows "Unable To Save" error but somehow again shows Email channel running.

I can reproduce same issue on my side, when I do Email channel configuration on Azure portal, it shows **`Unable To Save`**, but if I click the **Channels** blade, I can find Email channel is **running** and the bot could help send a respond email.

[image]

It seems a portal issue, you can try to report it to Azure team.

[image]

Besides, [the Email channel currently works with Office 365 only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-email#configure-email-credentials). please make sure that you provide correct Office 365 credentials in the Email channel configuration.

> On receiving a new email in Inbox, Email channel gives error as There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Internal Server Error".

The error might be caused by your bot code, you can try to create and register a new bot with simple response message, such as “Hi! I received an email!”, and check if the bot can send a respond email when a new email arrives in Inbox.